# Export xls.sheet into a groups of pages, iReport java

Tags: jasper-reports

I wan't to export a Jasper Report to Pdf & Excel.

1. When the export type is PDF : i need the pagination of document to
   be ignored.
2. When the type id EXcel :  i need even page on an excel sheet and rename these sheet's by the label of the un-repeated group.

Answer (score 0):

To print the whole document in a single page, your report must ignore pagination by default. For this, you've to check **ignore pagination** to **true**.

> Your_Report >> Properties >> ignore pagination = true

For excel sheet's, add the following variable in a field that changes for each group, it makes it possible to do the jump for a new sheet.

```
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.break.after.row" value="true"/>
```

For change the name of the sheet dynamically on excel, you can use :

```
<propertyExpression name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.sheet.name"><![CDATA[$F{libUniteOrg}]]></propertyExpression>
```